# Magento 2.3.2 redirects to empty cart after successful PayPal payment?

Tags: magento2, paypal

After I updated from 2.2.3 to 2.3.2 I am being redirected to the empty shopping cart after a successful PayPal payment. The order is created normally I just get the empty cart instead of the success page. The logs contain nothing helpful.

Any ideas where to look? I emptied the cache, recompiled, deployed the content, deleted the /generated folder. Nothing helped.

Thanks!

Comment: Using vanilla paypal extension?

Comment: Yes, the vanilla one

Comment: Is there any working solution by now? We have the same issue only with payments via Paypal.

Answer (score 2):

I face same issue on magento 2.3.4-p2 with Gene Braintree Paypal

Logs was showing 302 redirects after payment. Session was timetout and this happen when you enter on that point checkout/onepage/success/ its simply redirecting to empty basket.

Solution that work for me if you use Redis:

php bin/magento setup:config:set --session-save-redis-break-after-frontend=15

this change break_after_frontend in

> app/etc/env.php

```
'session' => [
    'save' => 'redis',
    'redis' => [
        'host' => 'yourhost',
        'port' => 'yourport',
        'password' => '',
        'timeout' => '2.5',
        'persistent_identifier' => '',
        'database' => '2',
        'compression_threshold' => '2048',
        'compression_library' => 'gzip',
        'log_level' => '1',
        'max_concurrency' => '12',
        'break_after_frontend' => '15',
        'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
        'first_lifetime' => '600',
        'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
        'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
        'disable_locking' => '0',
        'min_lifetime' => '60',
        'max_lifetime' => '2592000'
    ]
],
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer for this issue but I haven't seen too many people say if it fixes the problem. Has anyone found success with this change?

Comment: Me for example but I use Gene Braintree PayPal solution. This issue happen actually after switch to this module. REDIS on elastic cache AWS

Comment: It works for me with Magento 2.4.4-p4

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by remove static blocks (like general business terms) from the order confirmation email template